# Why is the @Repository annotation necesssary on a JpaRepository?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have the following repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    Employee findByName(String name);
}
```

Assume `Employee` is your usual entity class with id, name and surname.

I wire this class to my `EmployeeService` and use it like this:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repository;

    public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        return repository.save(employee);
    }
}
```

Would it make any difference to add the `@Repository` annotation to the repository?

Example:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    Employee findByName(String name);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@Repository` annotation is not required on Spring Data repositories. Spring Boot detects repository beans based on the fact that they extend the `Repository` interface.

In fact, you need to suppress this behavior using `@NoRepositoryBean` if you want the repository bean to **not** be created.

The `@Repository` annotation is a specialization of `@Component`. If you were implementing repositories without the help of Spring Data, you could annotate them with `@Repository` to declare them as beans *as well as* hint at their role in your app.

Comment: In fact, by adding the `@Repository` annotation to such interfaces, you create warnings in the log, which are written by the bean scanner, because it sees the annotation, but it's not on a proper class, which can be instantiated as a bean (this was asked in a question just a few days ago here).